# XAML: can't set "Window" property with a setter or a trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have trouble setting the height of a `Window` in a WPF application, from the XAML side (it works if I do it in the code behind, but I want to do everything in the XAML).
It's a pretty basic application: you click a button, the button gets disabled and a progress bar displays for 5 s (the progress bar is not processed in the following code).
I managed to disable to button when it's click thanks to a variable in the code behind, but the same mechanism for the `Window` doesn't work.
My code behind, pretty straightforward:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfProgressBarXaml
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _IsWaiting;
        /// <summary>Property indicating whether the program is in wait mode or not.</summary>
        public bool IsWaiting
        {
            get { return this._IsWaiting; }
            set
            {
                this._IsWaiting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsWaiting");
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            IsWaiting = false;

            DataContext = this;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsWaiting = true;
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            IsWaiting = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And my XAML:

```cs
<Window x:Class="WpfProgressBarXaml.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfProgressBarXaml"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="mainWindow"
        Title="Progress bar test" Height="120" Width="250">

    <!-- style for window doesn't work. -->
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="120" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWaiting}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="150" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWaiting}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="120" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>

    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Content="Click to wait" Height="50" Width="100" Click="Button_Click">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWaiting}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWaiting}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As I said, the part where the button gets disable works. However, the same mechanism for the `Window` doesn't do anything.
Even that, the first `<Setter Property="Height" Value="120" />` should set the `Window` to the desired height, but if I set it to say, 200, the `Window` still keeps its original height of 120.
Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change height if you change **`MinHeight`** in `DataTrigger` and set **`SizeToContent`** for your `Window` at least to **`Height`** or to `WidthAndHeight`.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWaiting}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="150" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWaiting}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="120" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: I also had to remove the local `Height` value, but this answer is a little more complete and relevant than the other (but anyway, with the `SizeToContent` attribute, the `Height` attribute is kind of ignored).

Answer (score 1):

you are setting local value `Height="120"` for Window. Local values have higher precedence than other, e.g. from setter (`<Setter Property="Height" Value="120" />`). remove `Height="120"` attribute

Style for Button work correctly, because IsEnabled is set only via setters.

also DataTrigger

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWaiting}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
</DataTrigger>
```

is an overhead and can be removed because it just repeats defaul setter

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
```

Comment: Style setters work correctly for properties other then `Width` and `Height`

Comment: It appears the solution is a mix of your answers; I had to remove the local values for `Height` and/or `MinHeight`. Then, add the local `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`; after that, set the `MinHeight` in the window style and finally manipulate the `MinHeight` in the `DataTrigger`.

Answer (score -2):

You should change window property SizeToContent to "WidthAndHeight"

Comment: Nope. If I remove the `Height` and `Width` in the `Window` and if I add this property, the designer display the height set in `<Setter Property="Height" Value="120" />` but at runtime it still doesn't work (initially and after the button has been clicked).